# Removing tuples of a list to make just a tuple Python

Tags: python, list, loops, set, tuples

Trying to turn a list of tuple with # inside to just a tuple  of numbers minus the []. So basically remove the brackets from a list of tuples.

Input: [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 4), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 9)]
Output: (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 4), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 9)

What I've tried:

```
list1 = [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 4), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 9)]
tuples=()
for i in list1:
    tuples.append(i)
```

> ```
> Error: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'
> ```

Comment: tuple is an immutable data type. You can't append to it.

Comment: It isn't very clear what you're trying to do. You can't "remove the brackets", since they aren't a part of the list; they're just part of the representation. If you want to remove them only for the purposes of printing, you can do `", ".join(str(tup) for tup in list1)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to convert a list of tuples to a *tuple* of tuples, there's a very simple solution-

```
tuples_version = tuple(list1)
```

This expression yields `((0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 4), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 9))`, which is what I believe you wanted.